# Remove my Dev-Account from Google Play Console Projects

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I have a Google Developer account for developing android apps and my account is linked to some projects that I don't want to be linked with anymore. I asked those companies to remove me as a developer from their Google Play account but they don't do it. I just want to be removed from their project because I have nothing to do with it anymore so why should I have access. It is just a weak point.

I know that the account owner of the customers Google Play account can remove my account from the project but there must be a way from my side as well to say -> I don't want to be part of it anymore and unlink from this project?!

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same issue.

Comment: No! I chatted with the Console Support last week and handed them the account id's I wanted to be unlinked with. They told me to unlink my profile but I'm still linked to all of the accounts. So nothing happened.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am linked to 3 accounts but I only work for one now. And every time I log in I have to switch account.

Comment: Have the exact same issue on my account. I can not remove the project of a previous company.

Comment: What I did (expect contacting the project amministrator) was to contact google trough their support using support.google.com, going in the play console section and contacting them through the button on the top right.
Expect this i didn't find anything working but they did do remove me from the project (took 2 business days)